# Go Firebase Cloud Messaging Client

Tags: firebase, go, firebase-cloud-messaging

Going through Google's [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging), are Firebase Cloud Messaging Client Libraries only allowed on iOS, Android, Unity, C++ and NodeJS?

I'd like to build a client written in Go that can be pushed messages. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

The protocol for **receiving** FCM messages it not documented. This means you need to use one of the official SDKs to be able to receive messages, and those are indeed only available for iOS, Android, and Web applications.

Comment: Frank any idea why you wouldn't support GO? Or is it in the works?

Comment: It has nothing to do with the language in a sense, but much more with the platform on which you run. For example: the Unity libraries wrap the Android and iOS SDK to expose their functionality to Unity developers. You could in theory do the same with Go, but only on a platform for which there is already an SDK.

Comment: Yep I get that it had nothing to do with the language. I'm just curious why Google didn't make an SDK in their own home grown language.